# Why does gcc add this movss instruction only with _mm_set_ss?

Tags: c, optimization, sse, compiler-optimization

Consider these two functions using SSE:

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>

int ftrunc1(float f) {
    return _mm_cvttss_si32(_mm_set1_ps(f));
}

int ftrunc2(float f) {
    return _mm_cvttss_si32(_mm_set_ss(f));
}
```

Both are exactly the same in behaviour for any input. But the assembler output is different:

```
ftrunc1:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    cvttss2si   8(%ebp), %eax
    leave
    ret

ftrunc2:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    movss   8(%ebp), %xmm0
    cvttss2si   %xmm0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

That is, `ftrunc2` uses one `movss` instruction extra!

Is this normal? Does it matter? Should `_mm_set1_ps` always be preferred over `_mm_set_ss` when you only need to set the bottom element?

---

Compiler used was GCC 4.5.2 with `-O3 -msse`.

Comment: Looks like another case of compiler optimization fail. Or rather, the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that the top 3 elements aren't used.

Comment: Yeah, the `movss` isn't needed in either case (on the other hand, other than the increased instruction length, it very well might not make a difference in terms of performance because the CPU treats the two sequences as equal internally). The compiler just isn't very good at optimizing SSE intrinsics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_mm_set_ss` maps directly to an assembly instruction (`movss`). But `_mm_set1_ps` does not.

From what I've seen on GCC, MSVC, and ICC:

SSE intrinsics that map one-to-one to an assembly instruction are generally treated "as-is" - a black box. So the compiler will only optimizations that apply to the entire instruction itself. But it will not attempt to do any optimizations that require dataflow/dependency analysis on the individual vector elements.

The `_mm_set1_ps` and `_mm_set_ps` intrinsics do not map to a single instruction and have special case handling by most compilers. From what I've seen, all three of the compilers I've listed above *do* attempt to perform dataflow analysis optimizations on the individual elements.

---

When you put it all together, the second example leaves the `movss` because the compiler doesn't realize that the top 3 elements don't matter. (It makes no attempt to "open up" the `_mm_set_ss` intrinsic.)

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a quirk of the peephole optimizer.  For some reason in the first case it figures out that it can fold the `mov` into the `cvttss2si` and in the second case it fails.  The question is, does it matter?  The extra move instruction is *almost* free -- it takes up an extra 4 bytes in the instruction stream and an extra decode slot, but both sequences require the same number of execution slots and the same number of load/store slots (which is what usually matters).  The only potential sticking point is the 4 extra bytes of ifetch -- but since ftrunc1 uses 10 bytes and ftrunc2 uses 14, both will fit in a single cache line, so you won't see any difference.  For minimizing that overhead, I'd be far more concerned about the unneeded %ebp cruft (are you compiling with -fno-omit-frame-pointer? -- I though -O3 included -fomit-frame-pointer by default).  You'll do even better by inlining this function, which will likely completely change what the peephole optimizer sees, and so may make it work better in either case (or even reverse the cases where it works better) -- there's no way to tell without compiling larger programs and looking at the assembly code.

Bottom line, there's unlikely to be any measurable speed difference between the two...

Comment: Doesn't the second piece of code have a false dependency on the old value of `xmm0`?